# Existe algun metodo para concatenar texto en un JLabel de java?

Tags: java

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if(e.getSource()==acept){
          //En esta parte ya he obtenido el texto del elemento JTextField
                   for(int i=0;i<sinpalindromo.length();i++){
                     String conversores="";//inicializo
                       obtengo=bajar.charAt(i); //Separo caracter por caracter la palabra
                      conversores=String.valueOf(obtengo);// convierto un char a string ya que al intentar mandar texto a la etiqueta no lo permitia
//Intento de dos formas la primera era con una variable que almacenaba letra por letra y la otra forma era un arreglo, ninguna me sirvio
//Mi objetivo es hacer que la palabra se imprima letra por letra por ejemplo escribo(oso) y empieza o-s-o  pero no puedo hacer que se acumule el texto ya que al momento de imprimir solo aparece la primera letra
                       arreglo[i]=conversores;
                       //System.out.print(conversores);
                        puntosc.setText(arreglo[i]);
                   }


               }
            }
        };
```

//Funcion addActionListener el boton se creo con el objeto de dicha estructura
            acept.addActionListener(palindro);

Comment: Ejemplo: `label.setText(label.getText() + "Hola");`

Comment: Con ese código concatenas el texto actual del label con otro.